# ASP email form wont send

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, smtp, gmail

I have my form up and running with no errors. However when I press send the browser says waiting for local host then stops and no email is sent. All of the smtp settings seem to be right. Heres my code however I have taken out my email and password details.

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"        Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
 <%@Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>
 <%@Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
<script language="c#" runat="server">

 protected void SendMail()
    {
        // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
        var fromAddress = "[removed]";
        // any address where the email will be sending
        var toAddress = YourEmail.Text.ToString();
        //Password of your gmail address
        const string fromPassword = "[removed]";
        // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
        string subject = YourSubject.Text.ToString();
        string body = "From: " + YourName.Text + "\n";
        body += "Email: " + YourEmail.Text + "\n";
        body += "Subject: " + YourSubject.Text + "\n";
        body += "Question: \n" + Comments.Text + "\n";
        // smtp settings

        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        {
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
            smtp.Timeout = 20000;
        }
        // Passing values to smtp object
        smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //here on button click what will done 
            SendMail();
            DisplayMessage.Text = "Your Comments after sending the mail";
            DisplayMessage.Visible = true;
            YourSubject.Text = "";
            YourEmail.Text = "";
            YourName.Text = "";
            Comments.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

        }
    }


</script>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
Tickets
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">



<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSubmit">
<p>
    Please Fill the Following to Send Mail.</p>
<p>
    Your name:
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
        ControlToValidate="YourName" ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="YourName" runat="server" Width="250px" /><br />
    Your email address:
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
        ControlToValidate="YourEmail" ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="YourEmail" runat="server" Width="250px" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="RegularExpressionValidator23"
        SetFocusOnError="true" Text="Example: username@gmail.com" ControlToValidate="YourEmail"
        ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" Display="Dynamic"
        ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
    Subject:
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
        ControlToValidate="YourSubject" ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="YourSubject" runat="server" Width="400px" /><br />
    Your Question:
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
        ControlToValidate="Comments" ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="Comments" runat="server" 
            TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Width="400px" />
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Send" 
                OnClick="Button1_Click" ValidationGroup="save" />
</p>
</asp:Panel>
<p>
<asp:Label ID="DisplayMessage" runat="server" Visible="false" />
</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the code? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Weirdly the code wont run from SendMail() ive put breakpoints but it doesnt reach it when i go through the process. Maybe the button isnt functioning...cant see why not tho...and no exception

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Remove `ValidationGroup="save"` from your `asp:Button` tag
2. Replace `Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());` with

   DisplayMessage.Text = ex.ToString();

   DisplayMessage.Visible = true;

Let me know what happens.